# 3Executing flutter doctor throws MutexLock exception

Tags: flutter

I have installed and configured flutter, which runs fine from the command line in the C:\Windows\System32 directory. When I attempt tpo execute flutter from the command line I receive a MutexLock:  Timeout exception after a couple of minutes.

Git has been uninstalled and reinstalled, and researching other entries here I have made a number of adjustments to my environment variables.

Can anyone help me solve this issue please?

Thanks.

---

C:\Windows\System32>flutter --version
Flutter 2.2.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f4abaa0735 (4 weeks ago) • 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
Engine • revision 241c87ad80
Tools • Dart 2.13.4

E:\Development\Android\Projects>flutter --version
MutexLock: Timeout ... from jlibAThreadData.c,361
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Download flutter zip, and put it anywhere you want, Then  set it's Environment Veriable from My Computer-> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Veriable

Try this out and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason why this was happening.  I also have the MultiValue database named jBASE installed, which was causing my grief.